# JavaScript code works on chrome and IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to run some small JavaScript code. I need to refresh data on a page (using a certain link) then I want to load that page with the updated data.

I basically have to open a link before opening the page to update the data due to the platform that I'm using.

I quickly wrote some JavaScript and tested it. It works perfectly in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, but for some reason it seems like it's not running the while loop in Firefox. I'm not sure why it's not working as I looked up the syntax and it seems correct.

```
var refreshed = false;
while (refreshed != true) {
  refreshpage = window.open('https://na10.salesforce.com/dash/dashboardRefresh');
  refreshed = true;
  refreshpage.close();
}
window.open('/dashboard', '__tab');
```

I tried using a timeout function for closing the window. But I'm not sure if I'm using it right. It will execute everything - including what's in the loop - but it never closes the window.

Here's the updated code:

```
var refreshed = false;
var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
  refreshpage.close();
}, 1000);

while (refreshed != true) {
  refreshpage = window.open('https://na10.salesforce.com/dash/dashboardRefresh');
  refreshed = true;
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
}
window.open('/dashboard', '__tab');
```

Comment: _"it seems like it's not running"_ use a debugger, see which code is actually being run.

Comment: Ahh, I used the wrong thing earlier... I just ran it and it says "Error loading source:
loadSourceError" For the onClick event that runs the code... So I removed the loop, and clicked it again. The last window.open will run correctly and open the page, it still gives the error even though it executes correctly.

Comment: Try using onclick without capitals

Comment: Note that you're giving the new page no time to actually load. `window.open` just **starts** the process, whereupon you immediately cancel it by closing the window. To actually ensure that the request gets reliably sent, much less responded to, you'll have to wait a bit.

Comment: I'm using Salesforce so the onclick is generated by the platform. I don't think thats the problem as it will execute the code outside of the loop. But for some reason it won't execute the code in the loop.

Comment: T.J. I tried using a timeout method to delay it a bit but that didn't help at all.

Comment: @user1072453 I tried using your code in FF, and it worked for me (used a different address to open).  I removed the `page.close()`, and I opened the page.  After adding it back in, no page opened in my browser.

Comment: Okay, so it works across all the test browsers now. I'll edit the question to show the final code that worked in case anyone else every runs into this kind of problem. I simply added a timeout and set it for 500 milliseconds which gives it enough time to actually execute the refresh on the data and then closes the window. Thanks for all the help and suggestions!

Comment: For something like this, I would suggest you use a hidden iframe instead to pass data through it.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

From the original post:

> Here is what I used to get it to work:
>
> ```
> var refreshed = false;
> while (refreshed != true) {
>   refreshpage = window.open('https://na10.salesforce.com/dash/dashboardRefresh');
>   refreshed = true;
>   var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
>     refreshpage.close();
>     window.open('/dashboard', '__tab');
>   }, 500);
> }
> ```